# Cannot seem to install pandas for python 2.7 on windows

Tags: python, windows, installation, pandas

Sorry if this has been answered somewhere already, I couldn't find the answer.

I have installed python 2.7.3 onto a windows 7 computer. I then downloaded the pandas-0.10.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe and tried to install it. I have gotten past the first window, but then it states "Python 2.7 is required, which was not found in the registry".

I then get the option to put the path in to find python, but I cannot get it to work.

How would I fix this? Sorry for the silly question.

Thanks.
~Kututo

Comment: Did you also install the 64bit version of Python?
http://www.python.org/getit/

Comment: I've installed the 32 bit version; do I have to uninstall that or can I just also install the 64 bit?
I'm really sorry for the question, I was told python was the easiest programming language to learn.

Comment: The language is, installing it isnt. But i think you should indeed install a 64bit version of both Python and Pandas. Both 32bit would also work, but wouldnt make much sense on a 64bit machine.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. Here is what worked

- Changed to PATH to include C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;
- uninstall 64bit numpy and pandas
- install 32win 2.7 numpy and pandas
- I had to also install dateutil and pytz
- pandas and numpy work import work fine

Answer (score 0):

After you have installed python check to see if the  appropriate path variables are set by typing the following at the command line:

`echo %PATH%`

if you do not see something like:

`C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts`

on the output (probably with lots of other paths) then type this:

`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\\Python27\\;C:\\Python27\Scripts`

Then try installing the 32-bit pandas executable.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the anaconda distribution for windows. Is free, comes with all the package you will ever need, and one click installation.

http://continuum.io/downloads.html